# MYSQL Insert for each Item depending on different item clasis

Tags: mysql, sql

i got my previous question answered and it helped a lot but now it gets a bit more complicated.

I have following tables:

```
Table: item
item_ID   item_Name  item_CLass
7          T-100     1
8          T-200     1
9          T-300     1
10         C-100     2
13         C-200     2
17         I-100     3
```

Item_Class of Item Table is connectet to the ID in item_Class Table

```
Table: item_Class
item_Class_ID    item_Class_Name
1                Pipe
2                Cable
3                Instrument

Table: activities
m_ID     m_Name
1        Test 1
2        Test 2
3        Test 3
4        Test 4
```

Then i have a middle Table

```
Table: cmc
item_Class_ID  m_ID
1              1
1              2
1              3
2              3
2              4
2              5
2              6
3              1
3              5
4              6



INSERT INTO `mt` (`item_ID`, `m_ID`, `mt_status`)
SELECT i.item_ID, c.m_ID, 'open'
FROM (SELECT i.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY `item_ID`) as seqnum FROM `item` i)
i JOIN (SELECT c.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY `item_Class_ID`)as seqnum FROM cmc c )
c ON i.seqnum = c.seqnum;
```

I tryed this but didnt got what i expectet.

What i expectet:

```
ITEM    mID  mt_status
7   1   open
7   2   open
7   3   open
8   1   open
8   2   open
8   3   open
9   1   open
9   2   open
9   3   open
10  3   open
10  4   open
10  5   open
10  6   open
13  3   open
13  4   open
13  5   open
13  6   open
17  1   open
17  5   open
```

But i got only this:

```
ITEM    mID    mt_status
7       1      open
8       2      open
9       3      open
10      6      open
13      3      open
17      4      open
```

What am i missing?

Thx in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a `join` between items and `cmc`:

```
select i.item, cmc.mid, 'open'
from items i join
     cmc
     on i.item_CLass = cmc.item_CLass
```

Comment: i dont get it, do i put this part into my query?

Comment: @ElGonzo . . . This should do what you want, if I understand correctly.